# How to redirect a main page and it's subpages on Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, redirect

I am trying to redirect a page and all of it's sub pages in Sitecore. It redirects the main page but not the subpages.
There are quite a few sub pages so rather than redirecting everyone of them separately I want to do it all together. 
for example:

/np/page/

After the "/" do i need to add any symbols for Sitecore to understand every page after the page or including the page?

Thank you

Comment: How, where are you trying to make that redirect? there are many options.

Comment: Hi,

the main page and subpages all needs to be redirected to one.

/np/page
/np/page/one
/np/page/two
/np/page/three                          to    /np/blue

I used Redirect Pattern and tried /np/page*    to include the page and it's subpages but it only redirected /np/page

Comment: Do you main you use SXA? Sitecore Experience Accelerator

Answer (score 0):

You must use a regular expressions, (regex)

```
^/np/page(/.*)?$
```

This regex is for /np/page and everything below.

With Sitecore Experience Accelerator you have out of the box redirects, that can handle regular expressions. See [Sitecore-Experience-Accelerator map-a-url-redirect](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/map-a-url-redirect.html) If you use another module, or method? be sure it support a regex input.